# 7.4.8 User Data Cleanup codeHs java

Tags: java, arraylist

My code is not correctly working I will include pictures of the assignment and the errors and the code
Assignment:
Your company is doing some data cleanup and notices that the email list of all users has been getting outdated. For one, there are some users with repeat email addresses, and some of the email accounts no longer exist.

Your job is to create a series of methods that can purge some of the old data from the existing email list.

Create static methods in the DataPurge class that can do the following:

removeDuplicates This method takes an email list and removes the duplicate email values. It also prints to the console which duplicate emails have been removed.
removeAOL This method removes all email addresses from a list that are from aol.com. It notifies the user which email addresses are being removed as well.
contains only emails This method returns true if all of the data in the email list is actually an email address. We will define something as an email address if it contains the characters @ and.
Test your methods out in the DataPurgeTester file. You don’t have to change anything there, but the methods should work accordingly!

Code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DataPurge
{
    public static void removeDuplicates(ArrayList<String> e)
    {
        String removed = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < e.size(); i++)
        {
          for (int x = 0; x < e.size(); x++)
          {
              if (e.get(i).equals(e.get(x)))
              {
                  removed += e.get(x) + "\n";
                  e.remove(x);
              }
          }
        }
        System.out.println(removed);
    }
    public static void removeAOL(ArrayList<String> e)
    {
       String removed = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < e.size(); i++)
        {
            String e2 = e.get(i);

           if(e2.indexOf("aol.com") >= -1)
           {
               removed += e.get(i) + "\n";
               e.remove(i);
           }
           if(e2.equals("gtaylor@aol.com"))
           {
                removed += e.get(i) + "\n";
               e.remove(i);
           }
        }
    }
    public static Boolean containsOnlyEmails(ArrayList<String> e)
    {
        int x = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < e.size(); i++)
        {
          if (e.get(i).indexOf("@") != -1 && e.get(i).indexOf(".") != -1) 
          {
              x++;
          }
        }
        return (x == e.size());
    }
}
```

errors

doesn't remove all AOL or duplicates

Comment: Think about what happens when you remove the element at the current index. What's the new element with that index? What's the index of the next element you check?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your current code is that you're trying to remove items from an array you are currently modifying. In cases like this you need to use more than one array or try a different data structure to help solve the problem.

I made this method return an array list with removed duplicate emails

```
public static ArrayList<String> removeDuplicates(ArrayList<String> e)
    {
        HashSet<String> hs = new HashSet<>(); // HashSet doesn't allow duplicates
        System.out.println("Removed from emails : " );
        for(int i = 0; i < e.size(); i ++){
            if(!hs.add(e.get(i))){ 
               System.out.println(e.get(i)); 
            }
        } 
        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>(hs); //Create a new arraylist from the hashset that stored unique emails
        return al;
    }
```

Then your `removeAOL(ArrayList<String> e)`

```
public static void removeAOL(ArrayList<String> e)
    {
        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println("Removed from emails ending in aol.com or @aol.com : " );
        for(int i = 0; i < e.size(); i ++){
            if(e.get(i).endsWith("aol.com")){ 
               System.out.println(e.get(i));
               al.add(e.get(i));
            }
        }e.removeAll(al);  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to demonstrate that you can do simpler and understandable ways. For duplicate detections, please use `HashSet` collections. Also, `Stream` are useful for filtering operations [Java 8 - Streams](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java8/java8_streams.htm). For email detections, please look at `Regex` concept.  It is a good way to recognise emails. Look at a good article about regex [Java email validation using regex](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/regex/java-regex-validate-email-address/).

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Removed Duplicates: " + removeDuplicates(Arrays.asList("a", "a", "A", "b", "b", "c")));
        System.out.println("Removed AOL: " + removeAOL(Arrays.asList("aol.com", "test", "taol.com", "aol.co")));
        System.out.println("Contains only Emails: " + containsOnlyEmails(Arrays.asList("tet@tes.com", "test", "@abc.com")));
    }

    /**
     * Removes duplicates from input list
     * @param input Input list
     * @return Generated new list all items are distinct
     */
    public static List<String> removeDuplicates(List<String> input) {
        // convert to hash list
        HashSet<String> setList = new HashSet<>(input);
        // return array list
        return new ArrayList<>(setList);
    }

    /**
     * Removes items that contains 'aol.com'
     * @param input Input list
     * @return Generates new list without aol.com'
     */
    public static List<String> removeAOL(List<String> input) {
        // accept only not contains 'aol.com'
        return input.stream().filter(e -> !e.contains("aol.com")).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    /**
     * Filters only emails from list
     * @see <a href="https://howtodoinjava.com/java/regex/java-regex-validate-email-address/"></a>
     * @param input Input list
     * @return Generates new list with emails
     */
    public static List<String> containsOnlyEmails(List<String> input) {
        // accept only emails
        return input.stream().filter(e -> e.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9_!#$%&’*+/=?`{|}~^.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+$")).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Removed Duplicates: [a, A, b, c]
Removed AOL: [test, aol.co]
Contains only Emails: [tet@tes.com]
```